# over estimating ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, model

When an ARIMA model over estimates, i.e if the forecast from the model is always higher than the actual value, what's the cause? The model i used was SARIMA (1,1,0)x(1,0,0).
Below is the time series data, the ACF & PACF and the time series plot. Please help me out with identifying the model.The 95% confidence limit is 0.183. I have the actual values for the year 2011 and 2012. [The excel file of my data](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/DOno6o9G8a/)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There might be any number of possible causes of different kinds. Perhaps you could be more explicit.

Comment: What $p$, $d$, and $q$ are you using?

Comment: @tony SARIMA (1, 1, 0) x (1, 0, 0). The errors are all negative.Am thinking the model is wrong

Comment: I don't see that the autocorrelation results add much to your question. What's `dyt`? The data would be more to the point.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to edit your question. I voted for reopening it because I think there actually is a chance for this to turn into a question we can help you with. However, we are not there yet. Please provide the data in a copy-paste-able format, nobody wants to type 120 values to look at. How do you know that the forecasts are biased upward? What is your holdout sample? Or are you talking about in-sample model fits?